# Reset setTimeout every button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

Here is my Code:

```
var sec = 10; 
var timer = setInterval(function() {    
    $('#timer span').text(sec--); 
}, 1000);
```

It sets a `setTimeout` for 10 seconds. I want to have a reset button that, clicked, calls `setTimeout` again with a 10 seconds delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do this by storing the result of your `setTimeout()` call to some variable, and then passing the result that you stored to `clearTimeout()` when the button is clicked, before scheduling a new timeout and assigning it back to the same variable.

Sounds a bit tricky but it's really very simple.  Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzDdq/

Comment: There is no need to pollute the global namespace. Avoid global variables.

Comment: @Šime - Your example puts just as many things into the global namespace as mine.  Using `var` in the global scope still creates a global variable.  Besides, the purpose of the example is to demonstrate the flow of setTimeout() -> some variable -> clearTimeout(), nothing more.

Comment: Usually, in my answers on SO, it is implied that JavaScript code is ought to be inside the ready handler (or load handler), and my attached jsFiddle demos demonstrate that.

Comment: @Šime - I'm not sure "demonstrates" is the best word to use.  It does, but only because you have the `onDomReady` drop-down option selected.  Someone unfamiliar with jsFiddle may have no idea what that option does.  A better demonstration might be to select one of the "no wrap" options, and manually include the ready handler in your code.

Comment: I've added a note below the JavaScript code block in my answer. I think I'm going to have this note in all my answers from now on - it improves the quality of my answers. Thanks for pointing this out `:)`

Answer (score 7):

HTML:

```
<button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var resetButton = $('#resetButton')[0],
    timerId;

function timerExpired() {
    alert('Timer expired');
}

$(resetButton).click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, 10000);
}).triggerHandler('click');
```

*Note: this JavaScript code should be placed inside [a ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)*.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QkzNj/

(You can set the delay to a smaller value like `3000` (3 seconds) - that will make it easier to test the demo.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>Div</div>

var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

function timedMsg() {
   console.log("timeout expired.");
   div.t = setTimeout(timedMsg, 1000);    
}

timedMsg();

div.onclick = function() {
   clearTimeout(div.t);
   timedMsg();
};
```